# Should repositories using Entity Framework DbContext via DI implement IDisposable?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have seen with examples of EF7 people injecting the datacontext in the constructor.

However, since DbContext implements IDisposable I fear that my repositories would also have to implement IDisposable, propagating through the code.

The examples I've seen haven't implemented IDisposable, but I'm not sure why.

***Edit***

To clarify
previously I was using the db context in the usual manner

```
using(var db = new SomeContext())
{
    return await from row in db.Table
        select row).ToListAsync();
}
```

Looking at the injection way of doing things the DbContext would be passed into the repository constructor, but would this repository have to implement IDisposable to dispose of the DbContext once Repository is done with?

Is there a risk with this DBContext hanging around if the Repository subsequently calls another repository class that changes its injected DbContext?

i.e

```
public SomeOtherRepository (SomeContext db)
{
    this.db = db;
}
```

*

```
public SomeRepository (SomeOtherRepository repo, SomeContext db)
{
    this.repo = repo;
    this.db = db;
}
public async TaskAdd(Row row)
{
    db.Some.Add(row);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    repo.AddSomethingElse(row.Id);
}
```

Comment: I suppose lifetime of the DI handled object are handled by DI container itself. In some cases a singleton object is not disposed at all

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to override DbContext.Dispose.

Unless you need to deallocate resources created in your customizations of DbContext, the base implementation the framework provides should be sufficient.

Comment: Sorry did not make myself clear in the initial question and have expanded on it. My question is not on my DbContext, but the class that is using it in its constructor

Comment: It depends on how you have configured DI, as @luca mentioned before. The danger in reusing the same instance of DbContext is that context.SaveChanges() could have unintended consequences.